# jQuery TinyTable broken when it resizes with a new structure of table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

It is my first time asking so I apologize in advance if there's something wrong in my way of asking.

Well, the thing is the following: 
I am doing the responsive design of a table. This table has been done with tinytable. 
So the problem here is that whenever I resize the table for the responsive design, it breaks all the functionality of the tinytable (cannot search, etc)-[picture of the table with responsive design new structure and broken tinytable functionality](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7w5zi8q4r3jfdg/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202014-11-14%2014.32.43.png?dl=0)-

I am resizing the table with javascript with the following code I did (I hope it could help):

```
/**
*This .js splits/rezises a table given into a desiderable structure
*/

/**
*Function that splits rows according to what you need
*/
function splitRow(rowOrig, tam_row, tam_col, col1, col2) {
var row = rowOrig.clone();
var cell = row.find('td');

/**
 *Setting mode of the table's rows by default to 'simple'
 */
rowOrig.attr({
    "modo": 'simple'
});


/**
 * New rows with the new structure
 */
var tr1 = new jQuery("<tr/>", {"modo": 'doble'});
var tr2 = new jQuery("<tr/>", {"modo": 'doble'});

/**
 *Modifying columns that are required
 */
//Date Column
var cellToModify1 = new jQuery("<td/>", {"rowspan": tam_row});
var cellAux2 = jQuery(cell.get(col1 - 1));
cellToModify1.append(cellAux2.contents());
tr1.append(cellToModify1);


//Details Column
var cellToModify2 = new jQuery("<td/>", {"colspan": tam_col});
var cellAux3 = jQuery(cell.get(col2 - 1));
cellToModify2.append(cellAux3.contents());
tr1.append(cellToModify2);


/**
 *Removing columns not needed
 */
cell.splice(col1 - 1, 1);
cell.splice(col2 - 2, 1);


/**
 *Adding content of the rest of the columns
 */
for (var j = 0; j < cell.length; j++) {
    var cell_aux = jQuery(cell.get(j));
    var cell_td = new jQuery("<td/>", {});

    cell_td.append(cell_aux.contents());
    tr2.append(cell_td);
}

/**
 *Replacing rows
 */
tr1.insertAfter(rowOrig);
tr2.insertAfter(tr1);
}

function partir(){
var modoDoble = jQuery("#cabLineasCaja tr[modo='doble']:visible").length > 0;
if (modoDoble) {
    jQuery(window).unbind("resize", partir);
    var nColumns = jQuery('#bodyRowsCaja tr:first td').length;
    jQuery('#bodyRowsCaja tr').each(function(i, rRow) {
        splitRow(jQuery(rRow), 2, nColumns - 2, 1, 6);
    });
 }
}

/**
* Documento cargado/Document loaded
*/
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(window).bind("resize", partir);
   partir();

});
```

And the html is like that:

```
<div id="tablacaja" colspan="2">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tinytable" id="tCaja">
                    <thead id="cabLineasCaja">
                        <tr modo="simple">
                            <th><h3><?php echo _("Fecha") ?></h3></th>
                            <th><h3><?php echo _("Tipo") ?></h3></th>
                            <th><h3><?php echo _("Forma") ?></h3></th>
                            <th><h3><?php echo _("Nº Fac.") ?></h3></th>
                            <th><h3><?php echo _("Nº Rec.") ?></h3></th>
                            <th><h3><?php echo _("Detalles") ?></h3></th>
                            <th><h3><?php echo _("Importe") ?></h3></th>
                            <th><h3><?php echo _("Acciones") ?></h3></th>
                        </tr>
                            <tr modo="doble">
                                 <th rowspan="2"><h3><?php echo _("Fecha") ?></h3></th>
                                 <th colspan="6"><h3><?php echo _("Detalles") ?></h3></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr modo="doble">
                                <th><h3><?php echo _("Tipo") ?></h3></th>
                                <th><h3><?php echo _("Forma") ?></h3></th>
                                <th><h3><?php echo _("Nº Fac.") ?></h3></th>
                                <th><h3><?php echo _("Nº Rec.") ?></h3></th>
                                <th><h3><?php echo _("Importe") ?></h3></th>
                                <th><h3><?php echo _("Acciones") ?></h3></th>
                            </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody id="bodyRowsCaja">
                    <?php
                    $formas = explode("@", $forma);
                    $formaBusqueda = $formas[0];
                    if($formas[1]){
                    $idListadoBusqueda = $formas[1];
                    }else{
                       $idListadoBusqueda = 0;
                    }
                    $lista = $capunte->listarApuntes($uActual->getIdEmpresa(), $fini, $ffin, $tipo, $formaBusqueda, -1, $filtroUsuario, $idListadoBusqueda);
                    $total_efectivo = 0;
                    $total_tarjeta = 0;
                    $total_talon = 0;
                    $gastos_efectivo = 0;
                    $gastos_tarjeta = 0;
                    $gastos_talon = 0;

                    if (!$lista) {
                        ?>
                            <td  >&nbsp;</td>
                            <td  >&nbsp;</td>
                            <td  >&nbsp;</td>
                            <td  >&nbsp;</td>
                            <td  >&nbsp;</td>
                            <td id="detallesColumn" >&nbsp;</td>
                            <td  >&nbsp;</td>
                            <td id="hideColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        $cuenta = 0;
                        foreach ($lista as $apunte) {

                            if ($agenda < 0 || ($agenda == 0 && $apunte->getIdAgenda() <= 0 ) || ($agenda > 0 && $apunte->getIdAgenda() == $agenda )) {

                                $cuenta++;
                                if ($apunte->getTipo() == 1 && $apunte->getForma() == 1) {
                                    $total_efectivo += $apunte->getImporte();
                                }
                                if ($apunte->getTipo() == 1 && $apunte->getForma() == 2) {
                                    $total_tarjeta += $apunte->getImporte();
                                }
                                if ($apunte->getTipo() == 1 && $apunte->getForma() == 3) {
                                    $total_talon += $apunte->getImporte();
                                }
                                if ($apunte->getTipo() == 2 && $apunte->getForma() == 1) {
                                    $gastos_efectivo += $apunte->getImporte();
                                }
                                if ($apunte->getTipo() == 2 && $apunte->getForma() == 2) {
                                    $gastos_tarjeta += $apunte->getImporte();
                                }
                                if ($apunte->getTipo() == 2 && $apunte->getForma() == 3) {
                                    $gastos_talon += $apunte->getImporte();
                                }
                                ?>  
                                <tr>

                                    <td  ><?php echo $apunte->getFechaInterfaz(); ?></td>
                                    <td  ><?php
                                        switch ($apunte->getTipo()) {
                                            case 0: echo _("Anulado");
                                                break;
                                            case 1: echo _("Ingreso");
                                                break;
                                            case 2: echo _("Gasto");
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        ?></td>
                                    <td  ><?php
                                        switch ($apunte->getForma()) {
                                            case 1: echo _("Efectivo");
                                                break;
                                            case 2: echo _("Tarjeta");
                                                break;
                                            case 3:
                                                if ($apunte->getIdListado() > 0) {
                                                    $tipoList = $clistado->obtenerListado($apunte->getIdListado(), $uActual->getIdEmpresa());
                                                    if ($tipoList && $tipoList->getId() > 0) {
                                                        echo $tipoList->getValor()."*";
                                                    } else {
                                                        echo _("Talón/Transf.");
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    echo _("Talón/Transf.");
                                                }
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        ?></td>               
                                    <td  ><?php
                                        if ($apunte->getIdFactura() > 0)
                                            echo '<a href="./facturas-ficha.php?ficha=' . $apunte->getIdFactura() . '">' . '<span style="color:#0000FF;">';
                                        $factura = $apunte->getNFactura();
                                        if ($apunte->getTipoApunte() == 3) {
                                            if ($apunte->getidContacto() == -1)
                                                echo '<a href="./caja-provee-av.php?ficha=' . $apunte->getId() . '">' . '<span style="color:#0000FF;">';
                                            else
                                                echo '<a href="./caja-provee.php?ficha=' . $apunte->getId() . '">' . '<span style="color:#0000FF;">';
                                        }else
                                        if ($cfactura->isCIF($uActual->getIdEmpresa(), 1)) {
                                            if ($apunte->getIdFactura() > 0) {
                                                $fac = new Factura();
                                                $fac = $cfactura->obtenerFactura($apunte->getIdFactura(), $uActual->getIdEmpresa());
                                                if ($fac->getIdRosa() != 0)
                                                    $factura = "CIF2/" . $factura;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        echo $factura;
                                        if ($apunte->getIdFactura() > 0 || ($apunte->getTipoApunte() == 3 && $apunte->getTipo() == 2))
                                            echo '</span>' . '</a>';
                                        ?>
                                        &nbsp;</td>
                                    <td  ><?php
                                        if ($apunte->getIdRecibo() > 0)
                                            echo '<a href="./facturas-ficha.php?ficha=' . $apunte->getIdRecibo() . '">' . '<span style="color:#0000FF;">';
                                        $recibo = $apunte->getNRecibo();
                                        if ($cfactura->isCIF($uActual->getIdEmpresa(), 1)) {
                                            if ($apunte->getIdRecibo() > 0) {
                                                $rec = new Factura();
                                                $rec = $cfactura->obtenerFactura($apunte->getIdRecibo(), $uActual->getIdEmpresa());
                                                if ($rec->getIdRosa() != 0)
                                                    $recibo = "CIF2/" . $recibo;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        echo $recibo;
                                        if ($apunte->getIdRecibo() > 0)
                                            echo '</span>' . '</a>';
                                        ?>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td id="hideDetalles">
                                                <?php
                                        echo $apunte->getDetalles();
                                        if ($apunte->getIdAgenda() > 0) {
                                            $ag = $cagenda->obtenerAgenda($apunte->getIdAgenda(), $uActual->getIdEmpresa());
                                            echo "<br />" . _("AGENDA") . ": " . $ag->getNombreAgenda();
                                        }
                                        ?></td>
                                    <td  ><?php echo $apunte->getImporte(); ?></td>

                                    <td ><div class="centro"> 

                                            <?php
                                            if ($apunte->getTipo() > 0) {

                                                if ($apunte->getIdFactura() == "" || $apunte->getIdFactura() <= 0) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <a onclick="abrirDialogo(<?php echo $apunte->getId() ?>)"  title="Anular" target="demo-frame"  class="acciones"><img src="_dt/img/acciones/delete.png" alt="Anular" title="Anular" width="20" height="20"  /></a>

                                                    <?php
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                        if ($cuenta <= 0)
                            echo '<td  >&nbsp;</td>
          <td  >&nbsp;</td>
          <td  >&nbsp;</td>
          <td  >&nbsp;</td>
          <td  >&nbsp;</td>
          <td  >&nbsp;</td>
          <td  >0</td>
          <td  >&nbsp;</td>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
```

And in the css I control it basically with this (it has more code but I think is not necessary to put all the code):

```
tr[modo='simple']
{
    display:none;
}

tr[modo='doble']
{
    display:table-row;
}
```

What I am trying to find is some ideas on how I could solve this problem.
I thought about maybe taking the information from the tinytable and transferring it to an another table. A normal one, to be able to resize it the way I want.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

Comment: What is a tinytable?

Comment: It is a tool to sort tables in javascript

Comment: Can you please provide a link to this plugin? I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: that's the problem. I am working for a company for 1 month, and they work with this kind of tables. I've being searching for some documentation to understand the functionality but I cannot find anything so far.
I have found [this](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/table-sorting-with-javascript-tinytable/) tho, but it doesn't say much. 
Looks like the official website where you were able to download it is shouted down.
If anyone who may have worked before with this kind of plugin could help me... :)

Comment: What I am thinking to solve this problem is, to copy all the data from the TinyTable to a new 'normal table' with the new structure that I want. The thing is that it may break the functionality of searching input that TinyTable has or other filters. As soon as I finish this try I will let you know if it works.
Any other ideas, guys?